# how to get all filtered rows from tablesort.js

Tags: javascript, tablesorter

I'm using this tablesorter library:-
https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-any-match.html

My html page contains of a table with 2 columns, Name and Age.
Say, a user has already filtered out all the Names which is aged below 18.
How do i get all the rows which match that filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the visible rows in the table:

```
$('.tablesorter tbody tr:visible');
```

You can try this in the tablesorter demo page, by running the code in the console.